# Multivariate normal, conditioned on inequalities

Tags: conditional-probability, conditional-expectation, multivariate-normal-distribution

$X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are jointly normal random variables with some mean vector $\mu$ and covariance matrix $S$.
How do I evaluate $P \left (X_1 \le x \mid \sum_{i=1}^nX_i \ge y\right )$?
Is there a quick and smart way for this?

How do I evaluate $E \left (X_1 \mid \sum_{i=1}^nX_i \ge y\right ) $?

Is it easier if $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ are independent?

Comment: General strategy: 1.Find the joint distribution of $(X_1,\sum_{i=1}^n X_i)$. 2. Derive the conditional distribution of $X_1$. 3. Compute the probability.

Comment: Specific feature for the expectation:$$\mathbb E \left (X_1 \Big| \sum_{i=1}^nX_i \ge y\right )=\frac{1}{n} \mathbb E \left ( \sum_{i=1}^nX_i \Big| \sum_{i=1}^nX_i \ge y\right )$$

Comment: Begin by simplifying the problem: the joint distribution of $(X_1,Y)$ is bivariate Normal (with known mean and covariance matrix) when $Y=X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_n.$ It's not any easier under independence of the $X_i,$ because $(X_1,Y)$ won't be independent.  Formulas for the integrals that arise can be found in our threads on truncated Normal distributions.